# Prometheus file_sd_config yml unmarshal error

Tags: yaml, prometheus

Getting error

```
level=error ts=2020-08-23T17:24:34.036Z caller=file.go:323 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=file msg="Error reading file" path=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!map into []*targetgroup.Group"
```

when trying to load a yml file_sd config.

Prometheus yml is

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:

rule_files:

scrape_configs:
 - job_name: file
   file_sd_configs:
    - files:
       - '*.yml'
```

The file_sd_config is

```
---
- targets:
  - x.x.x.x:9100
  - x.x.x.x:9100
  - x.x.x.x:9100
  - x.x.x.x:9100
  labels:
    job: node
- targets:
  - x.x.x.x:9090
  labels:
    job: prometheus
```

(real ip's obfuscated' The yml was converted from a working json file_sd_config.

Comment: Can you try x.x.x.x : 9100 . I think there should be spaces between value, :, key

Comment: What comes after targets is a simple list. The string is x.x.x.x:port#. Enclosing the list items in quotes results in the same error

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in prometheus.yml. If a json file is specified then the wildcard will work. I had to add the entire filename for the yml file for it to work

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:

rule_files:

scrape_configs:
 - job_name: file
   file_sd_configs:
    - files:
       - 'clients.yml'
```

Looks like a prometheus bug